# Valid Vietnam tourist visa in old passport

Tags: visas, vietnam, passport-renewals, portuguese-citizens

I get a new passport, but I have a valid Vietnam tourist visa in my old passport. Can I travel with both passports to Vietnam without applying for a new visa? (I'm a portuguese citizen).

Comment: @pnuts which means direct flights to Phu Quoc from another country. Maybe it depends on the season but when I checked last year I couldn't find any. I think used to be from Singapore and Cambodia.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked in Ho Chi Minh / Vietnam last week (Feb 2017) with valid visa in old passport. But had to pay USD 25 (single entry visa fee) and they issue new visa in my new passport and cancel the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You can still have your current visa transferred to your new passport. At Saigon airport, you’ll have to pay 15 USD for this work.

Another persons experience below:

*Arrived at Saigon airport with valid visa in a cancelled passport, together with my new passport. At Saigon airport I had to pay USD 15 to have the visa transferred from the cancelled passport to my new passport*.

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293921-i8432-k7530463-Valid_visa_in_cancelled_passport-Vietnam.html